# readonly typescript build errors in ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I'm upgrading from Angular 2 rc4 to Angular 2 release and, as part of that, have upgraded ng2-bootstrap to the latest version. However it seems to be struggling with the 'readonly' type in many of ng2-bootstrap's .d.ts files. When running angular2-seed's build process, I'm getting e.g:

```
Starting 'build.js.dev'...
.../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/buttons/button-checkbox.directive.d.ts(14,22): error TS1005: '=' expected
```

where line 14 is:

```
private readonly trueValue;
```

Any thoughts on where I should be looking to solve this?

Comment: `readonly` is a [typescript 2 feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-read-only-properties-and-index-signatures). Are you using typescript 2?

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer - should have thought of that! Will check.

Comment: Well that was simple - package.json was : "~1.8.10" - updated to "^2.0.2" - thanks again @NitzanTomer